# file_get_contents (“php://input”) returning one long string

Tags: php, ajax

I am tryng to send JSON over AJAX to my PHP but `$_POST` has nothing and `file_get_contents(“php://input”)` returns one long string.

AJAX code:

```
function sendData(userData) {
    alert(userData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'testLogin.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: userData,
        success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.error) {
            alert("error:" + msg.msg);
            showError(msg.msg);
        } else {  // send to redirection page
            alert("do something here");
        }
    },
    error : function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ajaxError:::" + textStatus + ":::" + errorThrown);
    }
    });
}
```

the alert before the AJAX shows
{"username":"user","password":"long hash here","op":"login"}

PHP code:

```
$user =  $_POST('username');
$pass =  $_POST["pass"];

$logString = "user: ".$user.
    " pass: ".$pass.
    " SERVER-REQUEST_METHOD: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].
    " getfile: ".file_get_contents("php://input").  
    "*\n*\n";
// my loging method 
logMe($logString);

$returnMsg['msg']= $pass;
$returnMsg['error'] = true;
echo json_encode($returnMsg);
```

This is what I get in my log file

userpassSERVER-REQUEST_METHODPOSTgetfileusernameasdpasswordcd8d627ab216cf7fa8992ca4ff36653ca6298566dc5f7d5cc9b96ecf8141c71boplogin

This is what I get at the return alert at success in AJAX
error: null

I can't decode the file_get_contents (“php://input”) because there are no delimiters.

edit: 
the logme function was breaking the logstring text. i have fixed that and this is what i have in my logfile now.
user:  pass:  SERVER-REQUEST_METHOD: POST getfile: {"username":"asd","password":"cd8d627ab216cf7fa8992ca4ff36653ca6298566dc5f7d5cc9b96ecf8141c71b","op":"login"}

so i should be fine i will just decode the file_get_contents(“php://input”)

Comment: Why can't you use simple `$_POST`?

Comment: The first line of your PHP code has `$_POST('username');` - is that a typo?

Comment: @PraveenKumar — Because the data being sent is JSON and not a format PHP supports for populating $_POST.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the string is being mangled by your `logMe` function, which you haven't shared.

Comment: "This is what I get at the return alert at success in AJAX error: null" — Since you are assigning a value from $_POST there, and you know $_POST is empty because you are sending JSON, that isn't unexpected.

Comment: Please format your log output so we can see it as you see it. Some  characters were stripped out of your post (eg, all the semi-colons `:`), so it's difficult to make out what the original log looked like.

Comment: @BeetleJuice — The question is asking why the colons and other characters were stripped out. Presumably that **is** the actual log output.

Comment: @Quentin I feel like I missed something: whereabout does the OP state that colons were stripped out?

Comment: @BeetleJuice — Last line of the question

Comment: He/she mentions delimiters missing from `php://input`, but the log output has more than just that. When I look at the code that generated the log, I would expect for instance the string "user: " in the log. This is separate from `php://input`

Comment: @BeetleJuice — That does lend credence to my theory that the problem is with the logMe function.

Comment: So basically the problem was that when the data was examined, it had been modified by some code that wasn't in the question, so the entire question was based on a false premise. The question really should just be closed. It doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem it describes.

Answer (score 0):

quention was correct it was a problem with my logging function.  i used it in my test just because i had it available but did not bother to look at it. it had a cleanString function in it that was causing my problems.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for pointing me in the correct direction. i was stuck looking at the problem as a php issue and was not able to see out of that box.

Comment: "so i should be fine i will just decode the file_get_contents(“php://input”)"  What you actually did to get the script working is what a couple of people suggested in answers, all of which were voted down.   The logging function wasn't working properly but that's not what was breaking the script. if you commented out that function and made no other change, the original script would still not work.

Answer (score -1):

This is another common way of doing it:

```
$entityBody = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
$data = json_decode($entityBody, true);
$username = $data['username'];
$password = $data['pass'];
```

Comment: From the question *the alert before the AJAX shows {"username":"user","password":"long hash here","op":"login"}* — It is **already** encoded that way. The problem is that it appear to be mangled by the time the OP looks at it in PHP.

Comment: Anyways, the second part of the answer is still correct for most of the times.

Comment: This solution, and mine by the way, actually solved the problem the OP stated: "I am tryng to send JSON over AJAX to my PHP but `$_POST` has nothing" .  I don't get why they're down-voted.  The `logMe` function not logging properly is a side issue because even if the OP removes it from the script, the problem will remain.

Answer (score -1):

change your format of userData to &username=something&password=something..

Comment: "First POST method in ajax have format like this" — It **can** do, but the OP is trying to send JSON formatted data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to populate the variables yourself. Because you're sending JSON, PHP will not build `$_POST` for you:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str);

if(is_null($json_obj)): //if there was an error        
    die(json_last_error_msg());
endif;

$username = $json_obj->username;
$password = $json_obj->password
```

Answer (score -1):

First, `$_POST` is a super global variable and it's not a function <strike>`$_POST('username');`</strike> `$_POST['username']`

And you said

> but `$_POST` has nothing and `file_get_contents("php://input")` returns one long string.

In the end,

```
$returnMsg['msg']= $pass;  ← ← ←
$returnMsg['error'] = true;
echo json_encode($returnMsg);
```

which `$pass` is equal to

```
$pass =  $_POST["pass"];
```

Instead, you should read the external variable from `file_get_contents("php://input")` itself. Following user function used to parse `file_get_contents("php://input")`, grabbed from [PHP docs comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#94607).

```
function getRealPOST() {
    $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $vars = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $nv = explode("=", $pair);
        $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
        $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

And use along with your codes

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"); //to return the response as json
$post = getRealPOST(); //parse the POST
$user =  $post["username"];
$pass =  $post["pass"];

$logString = "user: ".$user.
    " pass: ".$pass.
    " SERVER-REQUEST_METHOD: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].
    " getfile: ".file_get_contents("php://input").  
    "*\n*\n";
// my loging method 
logMe($logString);

$returnMsg['msg']= $pass;
$returnMsg['error'] = true;
echo json_encode($returnMsg);
```

Comment: `explode("&"` — that isn't how JSON data, which is what is being posted to the script, is parsed … and the question was asking about why the data being mangled when it came out of `file_get_contents("php://input")` (and was based on a false premise so should be closed anyway).